# Parameters can't be updated when using torch.nn.DataParallel to train on multiple GPUs

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, gpu, dataparallel

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import os

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.h = -1
    def forward(self, x):
        self.h =x

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print('using Cuda devices, num:', torch.cuda.device_count())

model = nn.DataParallel(Net())
x = 2
print(model.module.h)
model(x)
print(model.module.h)
```

When I use multiple GPUs to train my model, I find that the Net's params can't be updated correctly, it remains the initial value. However, when I use only one GPU instead, it's can be correctly updated. How can I fix this problem? thx! (The examples are posted in the image)

This is when I using two GPUs, the param 'h' didn't change:

[image]

This is when I using only one GPU, the param 'h' had changed:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PyTorch's documentation (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html):

> In each forward, `module` is replicated on each device, so any updates to the running module in `forward` will be lost. For example, if `module` has a counter attribute that is incremented in each forward, it will always stay at the initial value because the update is done on the replicas which are destroyed after `forward`.

I am guessing PyTorch skips the copying part when there is only one GPU.
Also, your `h` is just an attribute. It is not a "parameter" in PyTorch.